# Gulp task is causing my Node process to hang

Tags: node.js, gulp, git-bash

I'm trying to run the 'rundev' task in the following gulp code but it keeps     causing my Node/Gulp process to hang. I can't unhang them without restarting my computer so tracking down the problem has proven difficult.

```
const gulp = require("gulp");
const concat = require("gulp-concat");
const uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
const uglifycss = require("gulp-uglifycss");
const del = require("del");
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const streamqueue = require('streamqueue');
const gzip = require('gulp-gzip');
const compression = require('compression');
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();

const scripts = require("./scripts");
const styles = require("./styles");

var devMode = false;

gulp.task("html", function() {
    gulp.src("./src/html/**/*.html")
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))
        /*.pipe(gzip({extension: 'gz'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/"))*/
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task("css", function() {
    var cssRaw = gulp.src(styles["css"])
        .pipe(uglifycss());
    var cssFromSass = gulp.src(styles["scss"])
        .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'compressed'}));

    return streamqueue({objectMode: true},
                       cssFromSass, 
                       cssRaw)
        .pipe(concat("allStyles.min.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))
        /*.pipe(gzip({extension: 'gz'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/css"))*/
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task("js", function() {
    var jsMin = gulp.src(scripts["min"]);

    var jsOther = gulp.src(scripts["other"])
        .pipe(uglify());

    return streamqueue({objectMode: true},
                       jsMin, 
                       jsOther)
        .pipe(concat("allScripts.min.js"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/js"))
        /*.pipe(gzip({extension: 'gz'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/js"))*/
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }));
});

gulp.task("fonts", function() {
    gulp.src(["./src/fonts/**/*.eot", 
              "./src/fonts/**/*.svg", 
              "./src/fonts/**/*.ttf", 
              "./src/fonts/**/*.woff", 
              "./src/fonts/**/*.woff2"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/fonts"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task("images", function() {
    gulp.src(["./src/images/**/*.*"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/images"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task("sounds", function() {
    gulp.src(["./src/sounds/**/*.*"])
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/sounds"))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
        stream: true
    }));
});

gulp.task("clean", function() {
    return del('./dist/**', {read: false});
});

gulp.task("build", ['clean'], function() {
    gulp.start(["css", "js", "html", "fonts", "images", "sounds"]);
});


gulp.task("browser-sync", function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        open: false,
        server: {
            baseDir: "dist",
            middleware: compression()
        }/*,
        httpModule: 'http2',
        https: true*/
    });
});

gulp.task("rundev", function() {
    devMode = true;
    gulp.start(["build", "browser-sync"]);
    gulp.watch(["./src/css/**/*.css", "./src/css/**/*.scss"], ["css"]);
    gulp.watch(["./src/js/**/*.js"], ["js"]);
    gulp.watch(["./src/html/**/*.html"], ["html"]);
    gulp.watch(["./src/fonts/**/*.*"], ["fonts"]);
});
```

I recently picked this project back up after a month long break and haven't touched the code since, yet I've never had this issue before.

I have this problem when I try to run 'gulp rundev' in my Git Bash window. It appears to complete without errors but never actually serves the files and I can't use the Git Bash window or even close it afterwards (none of these work: clicking exit, Alt+F4, or killing the process in Task Manager). The only way to get rid of it is to restart the computer. I'm using Windows 10, Node v8.9.4, Gulp v3.9.1, Brackets, and Git Bash as my development environment in case that helps.

Here's a copy of the output:

```
MyName@MyComputer MINGW64 ~
$ cd Documents/GitHub/PoeFilterEditor

MyName@MyComputer MINGW64 ~/Documents/GitHub/PoeFilterEditor (Development)
$ gulp rundev
[12:11:27] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\PoeFilterEditor\gulpfile.js
[12:11:27] Starting 'rundev'...
[12:11:27] Starting 'clean'...
[12:11:27] Starting 'browser-sync'...
[12:11:27] Finished 'browser-sync' after 114 ms
[12:11:28] Finished 'rundev' after 816 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 --------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.1.142:3000
 --------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.1.142:3001
 --------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: dist
```

I do remember getting more 'Starting' and 'Finished' lines in the output for the other tasks that are called by 'rundev' but otherwise the output looks normal.

Since the 'clean' task never reports as 'Finished' I assume the problem is somehow related to that and my research seems to indicate that the problem has something to do with permissions or the files being locked when it tries to operate on them. To this end, I've tried messing with the devMode, closing all programs except the Git Bash to call the task, and making sure everything is running with admin privileges, but it always hangs.

I'm a bit new to Node and Gulp so there may be something glaringly obvious that I don't even know to ask about, so hopefully someone here can help me learn my way through this.

Comment: When you restart, windows issues the same process kill signal to the application (does it show the "Waiting for background programs to close" when you restart?). Perhaps the terminal is foreshadowed by another blocking process. Gulp/grunt are just node processes so running `ForEach ($nodeProcess in Get-Process node) { Stop-Process -Id $nodeProcess.Id }` should do the trick.